# XamarinForms(Android)- InvalidOperationException: This operation is only valid on generic types. at System.RuntimeType.GetGenericTypeDefinition()

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, system.reflection

I'm having a rather odd issue where I'm using a DataTemplateSelector to populate a listview:

```
public class QuestionDataTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    protected override DataTemplate OnSelectTemplate(object item, BindableObject container)
    {
        if (item == null)
        {
            return null;
        }
        var types = item.GetType().GetInterfaces().Where(w => w.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQuestionViewModel<>));
        var type = types.First().GenericTypeArguments.First();
        if (type == null)
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not extract IQuestionViewModel<> generic parameter from {item.GetType().FullName}");
        }

        if (DataTemplateCache.Contains(type))
        {
            return DataTemplateCache.Get(type);
        }

        if (!(IocContainer.Instance.Get(typeof(IQuestionView<>).MakeGenericType(type)) is ViewCell page))
        {
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Could not create a view for type {type.FullName}");
        }
        var template = new DataTemplate(page.GetType());
        DataTemplateCache.Add(type, template);
        return template;

    }
}
```

Now, this works perfectly fine in DEBUG mode on three different machines.  However, when we try to run it in release mode or with a signed APK from VSTS Build Pipelines we get:

```
InvalidOperationException: This operation is only valid on generic types.
  at System.RuntimeType.GetGenericTypeDefinition() [0x00012] in <e12c8a98444d40b09ff73f6575530692>:0 
  at Spirit.Smartphone.Common.Inspections.Views.QuestionDataTemplateSelector+<>c.<OnSelectTemplate>b__0_0 (System.Type w)[0x00000] in <c2d5efcc31454b1989609d0a23094856>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable+WhereArrayIterator`1[TSource].MoveNext ()[0x0002c] in <f40c30bd170444e4afebf14b88d6b816>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.TryGetFirst[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source, System.Boolean& found) [0x00045] in <f40c30bd170444e4afebf14b88d6b816>:0 
  at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource] (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] source) [0x00000] in <f40c30bd170444e4afebf14b88d6b816>:0 
  at Spirit.Smartphone.Common.Inspections.Views.QuestionDataTemplateSelector.OnSelectTemplate(System.Object item, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject container) [0x00034] in <c2d5efcc31454b1989609d0a23094856>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.DataTemplateSelector.SelectTemplate(System.Object item, Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject container) [0x00035] in <2213e65041254f04b27ae6e57d256a86>:0 
  at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ListViewAdapter.GetItemViewType(System.Int32 position) [0x000e7] in <81626d5b2a054a23bc21d192df515fa9>:0 
  at Android.Widget.BaseAdapter.n_GetItemViewType_I(System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.Int32 position) [0x00008] in <86b02aaac0b44e61842dbba0cf915ee9>:0 
  at(wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.392050fa-08f2-49d9-91d8-72e79027d071(intptr, intptr, int)
```

From like

```
    var types = item.GetType().GetInterfaces().Where(w => w.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IQuestionViewModel<>));
```

Anyone got any ideas as to why we only see this in a RELEASE build?

Thanks.

**EDIT 1:**
Build in release with 'Use shared runtime' works.  Maybe, it's something about not having the MonoRuntime?

**EDIT 2:**
Setting Linker to 'None' stops the crash.

Comment: Are you using progaurd in your release build? and have you ever had this issue before or this happened like after an update of something of that sort?

Comment: We are not.  This is a new application so it was the first time we tried it in release.  If set Linking to 'None' it seems to work but I don't know enough about this stuff to understand why.

Comment: Check-in project properties(Android) progaurd must be on